# how can I pass in a single record to Array Controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Hope page is a static page without Ember. On clicking on a card I pass its id in a url param so that the Ember app can make use of it:

```
http://cards.com/category?category_id=2&selected_card_id=3
```

Application Route:

```
@controllerFor('creditCards').set 'content', App.CreditCard.find category_id: categoryId
```

I'd like to get the selected card and pass it to `SelectedCardsController`

```
@controllerFor('creditCards').set 'content', App.CreditCard.find category_id: categoryId
@controllerFor('selectedCards').set 'content', App.CreditCard.find selectedCardId
```

The problem is that `SelectedCardsController` is an **Array Controller** and when I try to populate its content this way I get the error of `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver'`

My question is: how can I pass this single record to the Array Controller?

Comment: is it a typo or why do you have `App.CreditCard` and `App.CreditCards`? is `App.CreditCards` a different model?

Comment: Yup, sorry, it's a typo.

Comment: I solved the problem - I used a method on the SelectedCardsController that adds a selected card to content (I use the method in my app). I think I could also get the content and use `pushObject` method in the route. :)

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to do this is in Ember is to use `needs`. Instead of setting the `content` of the `SelectedCardsController`, you can directly lookup the property from the `CreditCardsController` or declare a computed property to make local lookup easier.

```
App.SelectedCardsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: 'credit_cards',
  creditCardsBinding: 'controllers.credit_cards',

  selectedCardId: function() {
    return this.get('credit_cards.selectedCardId')
  }.property('credit_cards')
});
```